# React Native: How to securely capture user's phone number

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native to develop my mobile app. For login, I am using user's phone number as 'unique' ID.

Because of some technical issues and problems in OTP SMS phone number verification, I have dropped this idea of OTP SMS for phone number verification. I am looking for another good way to ensure that the user has entered his/her **OWN** phone number correctly.

With OTP SMS verification, if user enters someone else's phone number in the app, the OTP SMS is sent to that other person, and so the (original) user is unable to enter OTP, as they don't have the OTP with them - and so the user's phonenumber is left unverified.

My question is, what are the other (good) ways I can use (different from OTP SMS or Voice call verification) so that I can ensure user is entering their **OWN** phone number when logging in?

I am wondering if I can extract phone number from SIM (hardware) directly and which **CANNOT** be tampered with or is difficult to tamper with. If there is some way like this - I don't even need to verify the user's phone number.

My question is specific to android.

Comment: You can try [react-native-sms-retriever](https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it in iOS, but there are libraries that give you device phone number in Android. You can [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info) or [react-native-sim-data](https://github.com/pocesar/react-native-sim-data) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at react-native-sms-retriever and react-native-sim. These may be able to help. But they this solution is only for android not ios